# '90s horror cartoon with a demonic lord and an army of different horror creatures

Tags: story-identification, horror, cartoon

I'm trying to remember a cartoon from '90s (not sure about the production time) which consists of a demonic lord and an army of different kind of creatures, from mummies to Frankestein's Monster kinda creatures.

One of the generals of the army was Prince Dimitri, cousin of Dracula. They were ruling in a glass-covered castle, as far as I can remember, and the theme had a mostly reddish sky. I think the demonic lord had a huge church organ.

I can't remember the good folks at all, or if this army was totally evil or not. I remember there were two factions. I'd appreciate it if someone can help me find it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you clarify what you mean by this cartoon being _"from 90s"_ but you're _"not sure about the production time"_? Does that mean you watched it in the '90s, but you're not sure when it was made? Or did you watch it more recently, and you're guessing it was from the '90s?

Comment: Also, was this a series or an animated movie? Did you watch it on TV, and if so, in which country and language?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I watched it in 90s, so production date might be older. It was a series as far as I can remember. I watched it dubbed Turkish but it must be western, probably American.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***[Darkstalkers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0229122/)*** (1995)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkstalkers_(TV_series)):

> *Darkstalkers* (also known as *Darkstalkers: The Animated Series*) is an American children's animated television series produced by Graz Entertainment and aired in syndication from September to December 1995. The cartoon is loosely based on the Capcom fighting game *Darkstalkers: The Night Warriors*. It ran for one season of thirteen episodes.

> As the television series was aimed towards a young audience, the violence and the sexual content present in the games were toned down. In addition, rather than following the complex backstory of the games, the show went for a standard good-vs.-evil plot. Various changes were made to the game characters themselves, most notably Morrigan Aensland, who became a villain descended from Morgan le Fay, and served alongside Demitri Maximoff (who was her rival in the games), under Pyron's command. The main protagonist is an ordinary human boy named Harry Grimoire, a descendant of Merlin created exclusively for the show, with whom Felicia forms a partnership.

From the Wikipedia page for [Demitri Maximoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demitri_Maximoff):

> **Demitri is a central character in the 1995 American cartoon series *Darkstalkers*,** in which he was voiced by Michael Donovan, while his backstory and physical appearance underwent many significant changes. He is illustrated with a peakish brownish-green complexion while his eyes featured red pupils early in the series before being changed to solid white. In the show's storyline, which itself strayed considerably from the games, Demitri is awakened by Pyron to be his servant and offered rewards for doing so. In the process, he forms an uneasy alliance with Morrigan under Pyron's command, though she also serves as his rival for Pyron's favor. Demitri is portrayed therein as cowardly, with his power stemming from his control of Pyron's weapons as opposed to his own strength. He seeks power from the Crystal Skull at Count Dracula's urging; thus armed, he nearly wins before being overpowered by Harry Grimoire, the show's bumbling juvenile protagonist. **Demitri is additionally responsible for the noncanonical demise of Anita's parents after attacking them and consuming their blood, and is depicted as Dracula's faithful nephew;** near the conclusion of the series, Dracula summons him and says that Demitri must take the reins of power as the new Lord of Vampires, as he is exhausted from his battles with Van Helsing.

Comment: I think that's it! Dimitri and their Red lord fit. I need watch more to be 100% sure. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

***[Drak Pack](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0220892/)*** (1980)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drak_Pack):

> *Drak Pack* is a 1980 animated television series about the classic Universal Monsters villains fighting for good. It aired in the United States on CBS Saturday Morning from September 6 to December 20, 1980. It was produced by the Australian division of Hanna-Barbera.

> The series centers on three young men: Drak Jr., Frankie and Howler, descendants of Count Dracula, the Frankenstein monster, and the Wolf Man. To atone for their ancestors' wrongdoings, the three, united as the Drak Pack, became superheroes.
>
> They appear initially as normal humans. But whenever trouble arises, they strike their right hands together and shout "Wacko!" This is called the Drak Whack. They then transform into a vampire, a Frankenstein monster, and a werewolf, respectively.
>
> Their principal mode of transport is an amphibious flying car which they called "the Drakster".
>
> The Drak Pack's principal opponent is Dr. Dred, a blue-skinned evil genius. His evil organization O.G.R.E. ("The Organization of Generally Rotten Enterprises" or "Endeavours") includes Toad, Fly, Mummyman, and Vampira.
>
> When the Drak Pack needs counsel, they go to Drak's great-great-uncle Count Dracula himself, known to the team as "Big D".

Comment: Close but I don't think it is. I'm sure about the character Prince Dimitri. The guy above him, their lord wasn't a vampire. I remember something more satanic but my memory may fail me at this point. Thank you though.